# Doing ajax call on response of another function but not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have registration form and i have created three function in jquery
First one is validate the form.
Second one is for checking the email uniqueness with ajax request.
Third one is for creating user this also with ajax request.

My flow on submit event  is that first i am calling validation function and then on the response of that function i calling the function to check the email uniqueness on the response of this a an ajax request is done to create a user.

First one is validate the form.

```
function validateregForm()
{   

if($('#u_name').val()=="" || !IsEmail($('#u_email').val()) || $('#u_pwd').val().length<6 || $('#c_pwd').val()!=$('#u_pwd').val())
{   
    if($('#u_name').val()=="")
    {
        $('#reg_error1').show();    
    }
    if(!IsEmail($('#u_email').val()))
    {
        $('#email_msg').remove();
        $('#reg_error2').show();
    }
    if($('#u_pwd').val().length<6)
    {
        $('#reg_error3').show();
    }
    if($('#u_pwd').val()!=$('#c_pwd').val())
    {
        $('#reg_error4').show();
    }
    return false;

}
else
{
    return true ;
}
```

Second one is for checking the email uniqueness with ajax request.

```
function chkmail(email)             {
var posting=$.post('http://localhost/tv100.info/index.php/user/chkmail',{u_email:$('#u_email').val()});
posting.done(function(data){
if(data=='success')
    {
        $('#email_error').css('display','none');
        $('#email_msg').css('display','block');
        return true;
    }
    if(data=='failure')
    {
        $('#email_msg').css('display','none');
        $('#email_error').css('display','block');
        return false;
    }
});

}
```

Third one is for creating user this also with ajax request.

```
$('#regform').submit(function(event)    {

var res=validateregForm()
event.preventDefault();
if(res)
{
    var email=chkmail();
}
if(email)
{
    $('#loading2').show();
var posting=$.post('http://localhost/tv100.info/index.php/user/create_user',$("#regform").serialize());
posting.done(function(data)
    {
    $('#loading2').hide();
     if(data=="success")
        {

        $('#reg_panel').append('<span id="reg_msg">Registration successful Now You are logged IN</span>');  
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
        $('#login').html('Logout');
        $('#sign_in').hide();
        $('#cmmnt_field').show();
        }
    if(data=="failure")
        {
        $('#reg_panel').append('<span id="res_msg">Something Went Wrong try again  Latter</span>'); 
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: can you please remove the extra tabs and spaces and indent it properly?

Comment: Try passing some value to `var email=checkmail()` <--here.. or remove parameter from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just telling the case

```
if(res)
{
    var email=chkmail(); // for getting the result in var email, ajax will wait until the success 
}
if(email) // In your case before completing the ajax request, javascript come to this line and won't return true. So it it always go to else part.
```

You can do the user creation on success of chkmail success part. It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Error in your first line of validateregForm() function,

change

```
if($('#u_name').val=="" || !IsEmail($('#u_email').val())
```

to

```
if($('#u_name').val() =="" || !IsEmail($('#u_email').val())

                    ^ `.val()` here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about asynchronously and synchronously concepts. Ajax calls are usually Asynchronously. Simple set the paramter `async` as false of each ajax request and you will get the result.  From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
async (default: true)
Type: Boolean
By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default).
If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.
Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.
As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback to process the result of email validation

```
function chkmail(email, callback) {
    var posting = $.post('http://localhost/tv100.info/index.php/user/chkmail', {
        u_email : email
    });
    posting.done(function(data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            callback(true);
        } else if (data == 'failure') {
            callback(false);
        }

    });

}

$('#regform').submit(function(event) {

    var res = validateregForm()
    event.preventDefault();
    if (res) {
        chkmail($('#u_email').val(), function(valid) {
            if (valid) {
                $('#email_error').css('display', 'none');
                $('#email_msg').css('display', 'block');
                $('#loading2').show();
                var posting = $.post('http://localhost/tv100.info/index.php/user/create_user', $("#regform").serialize());
                posting.done(function(data) {
                    $('#loading2').hide();
                    if (data == "success") {
                        $('#reg_panel').append('<span id="reg_msg">Registration successful Now You are logged IN</span>');
                        $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
                        $('#login').html('Logout');
                        $('#sign_in').hide();
                        $('#cmmnt_field').show();
                    }
                    if (data == "failure") {
                        $('#reg_panel').append('<span id="res_msg">Something Went Wrong try again  Latter</span>');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#email_msg').css('display', 'none');
                $('#email_error').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
    }
});
```